# I have a function defined on integer-radian inputs from the unit circle in the complex plane. Is it discontinuous?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, continuity

Recently, some colleagues and I had need to consider the following function defined on a part of the complex plane
 $$f:(e^{in},e^{im})\quad\mapsto\quad e^{inm},$$
where $n$ and $m$ are non-negative integers. Because these are integer radian angles, it follows that the numbers of the form $e^{in}$ are dense on the unit circle, and we only consider the function $f$ on input of the form $e^{in}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Notice that the function $f$ is continuous in each coordinate separately, since if one fixes the first input value at $e^{in}$, then $f(e^{in},z)$ agrees with $z^n$ for $z$ in its domain, and similarly $f(z,e^{im})=z^m$, when $m$ is fixed, and in each case these are continuous unary functions.

But I believe that the function $f$ is likely discontinuous as a binary function on its domain.

Can you prove it?

Comment: $f(1,1) = 1$, but shouldn't there be points arbitrarily close to $(1,1)$ that map to arbitrarily close to -1?

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving That is indeed the kind of thing I suspect is true. But what is your argument?

Comment: Well, if it's continuous it would be uniformly continuous, but you can fix one argument to give it arbitrarily large jumps over small intervals.

Comment: How do you get uniform continuity? The domain is not compact, since the function is only defined on a countable dense subset of the (square of the) unit circle.

Comment: Very true!  So much for that one line attempt.

Comment: Huh, it would be convenient if we could assume that the irrationality measure of $1/\pi$ is 2. :)

Comment: I have a solution now, sent to me by email from Alex Wilkie. I'll have a chance to post it later.

Comment: What motivated this question? I'm curious because it looks like something I'm studying.

Comment: @Robert This function appeared initially in the context of this problem: https://twitter.com/JDHamkins/status/1006651518534213633?s=19. It doesn't actually work, though, since it is discontinuous. Meanwhile, we have another solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Alex Wilkie sent me the following argument by email, and I post it transcribed here with his permission.

[image: Alex Wilkie's argument]

> **Transcription.**
>
> Let $$2\leq N_0 < N_1 <\cdot$$ and $$1\leq k_0 < k_1 <\cdots$$ be
>   strictly increasing sequences of integers, and $$t_0, t_1, \ldots$$
>   a sequence of real numbers with
>    $$(\ast)\qquad 2\pi k_j-N_j = \frac{t_j}{N_{j-1}}$$
>   and
>    $$(\ast\ast) \qquad \frac{\pi}{2} \leq |t_j| \leq \pi.$$
>   Such sequences are easy to construct using Dirichlet's theorem
>   (and, of course, the fact that $\pi$ is irrational).
>
> Then, by $(\ast)$, we have
>    $$e^{iN_j}=e^{i(2\pi
> k_j-\frac{t_j}{N_{j-1}})}\to 1\quad\text{ as }\quad j\to\infty$$ and
>   so also
>    $$e^{iN_{j-1}}\to 1\quad\text{ as }\quad j\to \infty.$$
>   Hence, $f(e^{iN_j},e^{iN_{j-1}})\to f(1,1)=1$, if $f$ were
>   continuous.
>
> However, $$f(e^{iN_j},e^{iN_{j-1}})=e^{iN_jN_{j-1}}=e^{i(2\pi
> k_jN_{j-1}-t_j)}=e^{-it_j},$$ which converges to a point (if it
>   converges at all) in the left half-plane. $\Box$
>
> In fact, only a very weak form of Dirichlet's theorem is needed:
>   just that $|N\pi - M|$ can be made arbitrarily small for integers
>   $M$, $N$.